# angular-material-fileupload 'fileUploadInputFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use [angular-material-fileupload](https://nishantmc.github.io/angular-material-fileupload.github.io/index.html) in Angular 6.

In app.module.ts:

```
import { MatFileUploadModule } from 'angular-material-fileupload';
import { BrowserModule }       from '@angular/platform-browser';

imports: [ MatFileUploadModule, BrowserModule  ]
```

but I have an error:

> 'fileUploadInputFor' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: Do you use fileUploadInputFor somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this property with 'input'.
For example

```
<input id="singleFile" type="file" [fileUploadInputFor]= "fileUploadQueue"/>
```